# What was this '60s SF novel about a future in which very long-lived humans can try being another sex?

Tags: story-identification, sexuality

My vague memory is that a long-lived man gets the opportunity to live a phase of his life as a woman.

Is there a Heinlein book with such a twist? LeGuin? Any other SF novel or story I might have read in the '50s, '60s, or '70s?

Comment: Have you got any more details? Male/Female phases of life are the main theme of The left hand of darkness (Ursula Le Guin). In the Culture novels by Iain Banks people live very long and can choose their sex in different phases of their lives; but these date from the late 1980s and later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be thinking of Heinlein's [*Time Enough for Love*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Enough_for_Love) from 1973 - which features Lazarus Long, a more than 2000 year old man, who is bored with life.  His descendants offer him a wide variety of alternatives to give him something new to do (so that he will be motivated to not kill himself) - and one of those options is to have his brain put into a cloned female version of himself.

Alternatively, you may be thinking of Heinlein's [*I Will Fear No Evil*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Will_Fear_No_Evil)  from 1970 which has the brain of an old man (in his 90s) transplanted into the body of a young woman (her personality also continues to occupy the body - or the old man is hallucinating her - it's not resolved which of these options is the truth.

Comment: Sex changes as an aspect of a long life is also an element of Barley's *Eight Worlds* sequence, which was also 1970s.

Comment: True- Varley's "Options" is one example

Comment: i have done some more checking and i think the one i remember is Heinlein's I Will Fear No Evil, though i also read Time Enough for Love, but the online synopses did not seem quite right. I will track down a copy and confirm.

Comment: I knew Leguin wrote about gender, but i did not read her and the plot of Left Hand just doesnt match.

Comment: And thanks for suggesting Varley. The name is vaguely familiar. I read so much back then i am sure i have forgotten some.

Comment: Now i need to figure out how to mark this "answered" and give credit to Andrew for what i think was the one i was searching for, but also for the good suggestions from LogicDictates and DavidW. thanks all

Comment: Just click on the checkmark underneath the number to the left of my answer.  Glad to help out.

Comment: It's less a plotline than a fairly quick mention in the story of un-aging humans, but Poul Anderson's *The Boat of a Million Years* also discusses this idea, briefly.

Comment: I wouldn't have been surprised to see Chalker mentioned here... Gender-swapping seems to be a favorite theme of his.

Comment: "Orlando" is the ur trope I guess.